# Can I create an Enterprise Keyword by code in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint, there is a property called "Enterprise Keyword", you can create one by writing some random name and then you can assign it to other files.
And I wanted to know if there is some way to create a new Enterprise Keyword by code, preferable in JavaScript but if is not possible then whatever language that it works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to create a new Enterprise Keyword by code, depending on your scenario and preferences.

One option is to use the **JavaScript Object Model (JSOM)**, which is a set of JavaScript classes and methods that you can use to interact with SharePoint data and services. You can use JSOM to add an Enterprise Keyword column to a list or library, and then set the value of the column for each item. You can follow this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/add-enterprise-keyword-column-in-sharepopint-list-using-jsom/) to learn how to use JSOM for this purpose.

Another option is to use the **SharePoint REST API**, which is a web service that you can use to perform CRUD operations on SharePoint data and services. You can use the REST API to create or update an item with an Enterprise Keyword value. You can follow this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140248/how-to-set-an-enterprise-keyword-field-with-javascript) to learn how to use the REST API for this purpose.